# Security in Gitlab. With gitolite?

Tags: git, security, debian, gitlab

I´m working with Gitlab in Debian 8 for my own project goes well but i need more security for employees in a company.
I need that employees can not see important code for this company, i´m trying to use gitolite with gitlab but I'm not sure that is the right thing.
How i can implement more security in my proyects?

EXAMPLE: 
employees work making a web interface using PHP functions. They can use these functions but can not read or edit the file containing these functions because they may have important data

Comment: You should not add sensitive code in gitlab. You can untrack those files and add them in the .gitignore. So that nobody can access it when pulling the data

Comment: I thought about it but if I ignore the most important files with .gitignore Employees may not work with them if they have dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, GitLab has replaced Gitolite with GitLab shell long ago: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell , I don't think it is compatible with gitolite anymore.

Next, why do you need to play with GitLab shell to hide code from emploees? Why not just:

- put the code on a safe server which employees cannot access
- only let employees access repositories through GitLab
- use GitLab's permission system to manage security: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/permissions/permissions.md

Comment: the company doesn't want employees can  view and edit important code. If we let employees access repositories through GitLab they can view important code for the company.

Comment: @LuisManrique using permissions you can chose who can view what. Why are the permissions not enough?

Comment: With the permissions they can view all files. The company wants a very specific level of security which Gitlab not give us, i think. Thank you for all!

Comment: @LuisManrique make it more explicit on your question exactly what level of security you are talking about, otherwise we won't be able to help you

Comment: Read the example that i put in question

Answer (score 1):

How about adding permissions to the files you want to keep secret? I mean, create a group, add people who will read and edit the file and finally, apply the changes by using chown and chmod.

Change the owner group to the group you want.

`$chown :[group_name] secret_file`

Remove **all** permissions from file.

`#chmod a-rwx secret_file`

Add permissions only to the group.

`#chmod g+rw secret_file`

But you will have the issue that the users/groups created in one computer will not be avaliable in other computers, unless you setup some domain or LDAP.

So, I suggest you to implement LDAP. I think is the solution you might need.